# Maximize $f(x,y) = x^{2} - y^{2}$ subject to $g(x,y) = 1 - x^{2} - y^{2} = 0$

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{maximize} & f(x,y) := x^{2} - y^{2}\\ \text{subject to} & g(x,y) := 1 - x^{2} - y^{2} = 0\end{array}$$

I tried solving this question using Lagrange multiplier and I had set up the following Lagrangean,

$$ L = x^{2} - y^{2} - \lambda (1 - x^{2} - y^{2}) $$

I got the following first-order conditions:

$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial x} = x +  \lambda x \\ \frac{\partial L}{\partial y} = \lambda y - y $$

I am not sure how to solve after this.
When I equate the FOC to 0 I get x= 0 and y=0 but if I keep x= 1 and y = 0  a larger value for f(x,y) is obtained which still satisifes the constraint.

Comment: Thanks for the correction I have made the changes.

Comment: Are you permitted to use an approach that has nothing to do with lagrange-multipliers?  For example $x = \sin(\theta), y=\cos(\theta)$ as implied by $g(x,y)$.

Comment: $\lambda = \pm1$ is a solution.

Comment: @user2661923 I think there is even no need for that. If this isn't an exercise on Lagrange multipliers, then one could simply argue that $x^2 - y^2 \leq x^2 + y^2 = 1$ and this is achieved at $(x, y) = (1, 0)$.

Comment: @WhatsUp Yes, I agree.

Comment: Why does equating foc to 0 give x and y=0? It could also mean that $(1+\lambda) or (1-\lambda)  =0$, have you taken those in consideration?

Comment: There are $3$ possibilities: First, $x=0$. Second, $y=0$. Third, $x\neq 0 $ and $y\neq 0$. You need to check all. But also you can easily show why $y=0$ must hold to maximize the function (suppose not).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your constraint is unit circle $x^2+y^2=1$, it is easy to see that you have maxima  when the objective function is a hyperbola $x^2 - y^2 = 1$ tangent to the circle and you have minima when it is hyperbola $x^2-y^2 = -1$, again tangent to the circle.

As far as Lagrange Multiplier method, you have

$x(\lambda+1) = 0$
$y(\lambda - 1) = 0$
$1 - x^2 - y^2 = 0$

From first equation, $\lambda = -1$ is a possible solution. Plugging into second, $y = 0$ and from third, $x = \pm1$.

Also from second, $\lambda = 1$ is a possible solution. That gives you $x = 0$ and $y = \pm1$.

That leads to maxima of $f(x, y) = x^2-y^2$ as $1$ and minima as $-1$.

You also have $x = 0$ from the first equation and $y = 0$ from the second but they both lead to the same set of solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Elementary option

Constraint: $y^2=1-x^2;$

$f(x,y)=x^2-y^2=2x^2-1;$

1)Min: at $x=0,$ and $y=\pm1:$

$f_{min}(x,y)=-1;$

2)Max: at $x=\pm1$ and $y=0:$

$f_{max}(x,y)=1.$